# How to call a class method given its name?

Tags: python, class, variables

I am attempting to call a class method by variable name that I extract from an external file, as seen below:

structures.py:

```
event_map = {'year' : 'get_year'}
```

Class code:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._analyze()

    def _analyze(self):
        event_method = event_map['year']
        self.event_method() #<--------------this doesn't work

    def get_year(self):
        print('here')
```

Comment: 'get_year' in your dict is a string, not a method.  Also you set event_method but then use self.event_method.  Also, event_map seems to be declared outside of your class, so it won't be aware of what `get_year` is.

Comment: Your example are strange and unclear, but you can try 'event_method(self)' on your real code, because in this example code event_method is a string and will not work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string is what you really want I think

Comment: "that I extract from an external file" what does this mean, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getattr` to get an attribute by name:

```
getattr(self, event_method)()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a `getattr(object, name)` function to call a function given its name as a string. You would use `getattr(self, event_method)()`:

```
lass MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._analyze()

    def _analyze(self):
        event_method = event_map['year']
        getattr(self, event_method)()

    def get_year(self):
        print('here')
```